# Can't connect to imgur.com or related content (i.imgur.com links work though...)

Tags: networking, dns, connection, imgur

I recently lost all capability to access imgur.com links (however i.imgur.com links work just fine).  I have tried: different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE; all the latest versions); Changing to a public DNS (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, and 4.2.2.2); Clearing the computer's DNS cache via command prompts; disabling my windows firewall; and clearing all internet history and cookies.  Nothing has worked so far.  I should note that I'm on a work network through a university, and a coworker that sits near me has no problem accessing the site and all related content (a problem with my computer?).  I also have performed a tracert for both imgur.com (times out eventually) and facebook.com (connects successfully) that I can post pictures of if that would help.

Comment: Are you with an ISP that likes to blacklist sites?

Comment: Since it is a work/school server I am not 100% sure...but like I said, a coworker has access, which is through the same ISP, so it is unlikely.

Comment: You could very well be blocked by the administrator then. I did that when I was a system administrator, blocking certain users automatically if they went over a certain traffic amount on certain sites.

Answer (score 1):

imgur's main site is on a different CDN (CloudFlare? Amazon Web Services?) than i.imgur.com (EdgeCast). You may just be having problems getting to that one CDN.

Comment: Well that explains that part.  Any idea how I might have lost access to that single CDN?